# Program works, but Code Academy doesn't recognize it as correct

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice <= 0.34) {
computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
computerChoice = "scissors";
} console.log("Computer:" + " " + computerChoice);

var compare = function(choice1, choice2){
if (choice1 === choice2) {
    return "The result is a tie!";
}

else if (choice1 === "rock") {

    if(choice2 === "scissors") {
        return "Rock smashes the fuck out of those scissors!";
    }
    else {
        return "Oh shit, that rock was not prepared for full coverage OF PAPER ";
    }
}

else if (choice1 === "paper") {

    if (choice2 === "rock"){
        return "Oh damn, that paper just covered the shit out of that rock!";
    }
    else {
        return "Those scissors cut that weak paper shit into pieces!";
    }
}

else if (choice1 === "scissors") {

    if (choice2 === "rock"){
        return "Wow! That rock smashed those scissors so hard into the ground that their grandparents felt it. And they're dead!";
    }
    else {
        return "That wimpy-ass paper was sliced into ribbons...Well, you know, if the paper was made of that ribbon material. BUT IT'S NOT.";
    }
}
} 
compare(computerChoice, userChoice);
```

The console returns the correct result, the code works, yet CodeAcademy says it's wrong. When I save and submit, the error message says:

> Your code returned 'That wimpy-ass paper was sliced into ribbons...Well, you know, if the paper was made of that ribbon material. BUT IT'S NOT.' instead of 'undefined' when the inputs are scissors and paper

What the hell is going on right now?

Comment: Both the console and [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t94bwtr8/) are producing the same result, so I don't know what you're doing to get `undefined`.

Comment: How does CodeAcademy check your answers? Do you need to return strings that match their output?  Is there profanity checking?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do everything like CodeAcademy expects you to do. Use the same variables name, the same code structure, etc.